# How to perform a find and sort on a Meteor collection (using Coffeescript)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, coffeescript

I'm new to Meteor and struggling to find any examples of using find and sort on a collection (and specifically using CS).

I seem to have a basic find operation working:

```
Tasks.find(done: false)
```

but am struggling to see how to add on a sort query to this? Are there any good examples of these queries? (Even in pure JS)? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A brief primer-by-example in JS:

```
Tasks.find({done: false}, {order: {status: 1}});
```

would sort by status ascending.

```
Tasks.find({done: false},{order: {status: 1, assignee: -1}});
```

will sort by status ascending then assignee descending.

```
Tasks.find({done: false},{order: {status: 1}, limit: 5});
```

will limit the results to the first 5.

For CS, you could define the options object itself as:

```
options = 
  sort:
    status: 1
```

and then do

```
Tasks.find(done: false, options)
```

Comment: Thanks Michel, these are really useful examples!

Answer (score 1):

You can see the documentation for `find` [here](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find). If you just search the docs for `sort:` you'll find several examples. Using your code above, you could sort your completed tasks by `completedAt` like so:

```
Tasks.find {done: true}, sort: completedAt: -1
```